# Как структурировать массив объектов, записав в подмассивы объекты, в зависимости от определённого свойства?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, объекты

Есть такой массив:

```
[
    {"value": "A", "level": 0},
    {"value": "B", "level": 1},
    {"value": "C", "level": 1},
    {"value": "D", "level": 2}, 
    {"value": "F", "level": 2}, 
    {"value": "G", "level": 1},  
    {"value": "H", "level": 0},
    {"value": "J", "level": 1}, 
    {"value": "K", "level": 1}, 
    {"value": "L", "level": 0},
    {"value": "M", "level": 0}, 
    {"value": "N", "level": 1},
    {"value": "P", "level": 1}
];
```

Как вложить объекты в подмассивы по свойствам `level`, в случае, если это свойство увеличивается? Вот пример результата для наглядности:

```
[
    [
        {"value": "A", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "B", "level": 1},
            {"value": "C", "level": 1},
            [
                {"value": "D", "level": 2}, 
                {"value": "F", "level": 2}
            ],
            {"value": "G", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "H", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "J", "level": 1}, 
            {"value": "K", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "L", "level": 0}
    ],
    [
        {"value": "M", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "N", "level": 1},
            {"value": "P", "level": 1}
        ]
    ] 
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ход мыслей:

Невозможно написать код, не понимая, что от вас требуется. Поэтому хорошо бы сперва по пунктам написать, что должен делать код.

• Циклом бежать по массиву объектов, каждый из которых имеет свойство-уровень. При этом создать второй массив (result), куда будут добавляться все объекты.

• Если уровень равен нулю, забыть всё и добавить новый массив в result.

• При увеличении уровня, создать новый массив и вставить его в текущий,

• При уменьшении уровня, выйти из текущего массива, вставить объект в родительский массив,

• Уровень не изменился: Вставить объект в текущий массив.

Т.е. надо как-то научиться запоминать все создаваемые вложенные массивы: Можно создать массив (стек). При вставке нового массива (увеличении уровня), добавить ссылку на него в стек. При уменьшении уровня: Удалить последний элемент из стека. В итоге он всегда будет хранить последовательную цепочку вложенных массивов.

```js
let arr = getArr();

let result = [];
let memory = [];

let curr_lvl = 0;
let curr_arr = null;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let obj = arr[i];
  let last = memory.length - 1;
  /* Формально, last и curr_lvl всегда равны. Но приятнее, когда для каждой цели
  есть своя переменная. memory[last] выглядит понятнее, чем memory[curr_lvl] */

  if (obj.level === 0) {
    curr_arr = [];
    memory = [curr_arr];
    result.push(curr_arr);
  } else if (obj.level > curr_lvl) {
    curr_arr = [];
    memory[last].push(curr_arr);
    memory.push(curr_arr);
  } else if (obj.level < curr_lvl) {
    curr_arr = memory[last - 1];
    memory.pop();
  } else if (obj.level === curr_lvl) {  
    curr_arr = memory[last];
  }
  
  curr_arr.push(obj);
  curr_lvl = obj.level;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2).replace(/{(.|\s)*?}/g, m => m.replace(/\s+/g, "")));

/***/
function getArr() {
  return [
    {"value": "A", "level": 0},
    {"value": "B", "level": 1},
    {"value": "C", "level": 1},
    {"value": "D", "level": 2},
    {"value": "F", "level": 2},
    {"value": "G", "level": 1},
    {"value": "H", "level": 0},
    {"value": "J", "level": 1},
    {"value": "K", "level": 1},
    {"value": "L", "level": 0},
    {"value": "M", "level": 0},
    {"value": "N", "level": 1},
    {"value": "P", "level": 1},
  ];
}
```

Comment: А если вдруг появится 10 уровней вложенности, То можно изменить мой код))

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно этот код упростить, но как быстрое решение пойдет.

```js
const LIST = [
    {"value": "A", "level": 0},
    {"value": "B", "level": 1},
    {"value": "C", "level": 1},
    {"value": "D", "level": 2}, 
    {"value": "F", "level": 2}, 
    {"value": "G", "level": 1},  
    {"value": "H", "level": 0},
    {"value": "J", "level": 1}, 
    {"value": "K", "level": 1}, 
    {"value": "L", "level": 0},
    {"value": "M", "level": 0}, 
    {"value": "N", "level": 1},
    {"value": "P", "level": 1}
];
const LIST_NEW = [];

LIST.forEach(item => {
  const LENGTH = LIST_NEW.length;
  if (item.level === 0) {
    LIST_NEW.push([
      item,
    ]);
  } else if (item.level === 1) {
    if (!LIST_NEW[LENGTH - 1][1]) {
      LIST_NEW[LENGTH - 1].push([]);
    }
    LIST_NEW[LENGTH - 1][1].push(item);
  } else if (item.level === 2) {
    let levelLength = LIST_NEW[LENGTH - 1][1].length;
    if (!Array.isArray(LIST_NEW[LENGTH - 1][1][levelLength - 1])) {
      LIST_NEW[LENGTH - 1][1].push([]);
    }
    levelLength = LIST_NEW[LENGTH - 1][1].length;
    LIST_NEW[LENGTH - 1][1][levelLength - 1].push(item);
  }
});

console.log(LIST_NEW);
```

Comment: А если вдруг появится 10 уровней вложенности?)